# Null poinnter exception with array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, nullpointerexception

I tried to learn basics for C++. Now I'm trying to figure out the arrays. But then i running this small program my IDE raise the null pointer exception.I didn't understand why this happend.

```
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
  cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
exit 0;
}
```

I searched for answers on google about null pointer exception. I understand what it is, but don't understastand why it raised in my program. My array has 3 items, so the i<4 statement is correct in my opinion

Comment: Incorrect. Your loop with the condition `i < 4` iterates over _four_ values: 0, 1, 2, 3. This is a counting exercise based in fact, not opinion.

Comment: It should be `for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)`

Comment: This doesn't even compile because it's not valid syntax. `int[] arr` should be `int arr[]` and `exit 0;` is definitely missing parenthesis. And you forgot the `#` before `include <iostream>`

Comment: c++ doesn't have a "null pointer exception"

Comment: This is not real code.

Comment: [Here is what the big three compilers have to say about your code](https://godbolt.org/z/E6a1MPbsv). If you get a null pointer exception from this code, your compiler is too non-Standard for most of us to comment intelligently.

Answer (score 3):

The array has three elements, but you are trying to access the fourth one on the last iteration. The condition in the `for` loop is wrong. (Note: you can calculate the number of elements using `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr` or `std::size(arr)`, since C++ 17.)

```cpp
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3}; 
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  std::cout << arr[i] << '\n';
}
```

To avoid this sort of issue altogether, use a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

```cpp
for (const int& x : arr) {
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Range based `for` loop! Range based `for` loop! Range based `for` loop!